# Recursive enable_if and type transform

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++14, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I'd like to add same number pointers from `typename U` to `typename T`, for example when `T = int***` and `U = int*`, the result is `int****`. So, I write the following:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename U,
          typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<U>::value>* = nullptr>
auto addPointer(T, U)
    -> decltype(addPointer(std::declval<std::add_pointer_t<T>>(),
                           std::declval<std::remove_pointer_t<U>>()));

template <typename T, typename U,
          typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer<U>::value>* = nullptr>
auto addPointer(T, U) -> T;

int main()
{
    using t =
        decltype(addPointer(std::declval<int***>(), std::declval<int*>()));
}
```

and I get the following on Linux clang 3.7:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ -lc++abi -Wall -Wextra a.cpp 
a.cpp:16:18: error: no matching function for call to 'addPointer'
        decltype(addPointer(std::declval<int***>(), std::declval<int*>()));
                 ^~~~~~~~~~
a.cpp:5:6: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = int ***, U =
      int *, $2 = nullptr]: call to function 'addPointer' that is neither visible in the
      template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
auto addPointer(T, U)
     ^
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:244:78: note: candidate template ignored: disabled
      by 'enable_if' [with T = int ***, U = int *]
  ...<bool _Bp, class _Tp = void> using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Bp, _Tp>::type;
                                                                         ^
1 error generated.
```

Why do I get the error?

Comment: Move the `auto addPointer(T, U) -> T;` version before the other overload

Comment: Using that many levels of indirection is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki `U = int*` works, but `U = int**` causes same error...

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what could you _ever_ use this for? :-)

Comment: @matz for my TMP practice library :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we're dealing with scalars, ADL will not look in the global namespace.  Not only can the fallback overload not be found this way, the overload you're currently defining cannot be referred to in the trailing-return-type.

With C++14, there is a nicer solution to your problem, which circumvents that issue:

```
template <typename T>
T addPointer(T, ...);

template <typename T, typename U>
auto addPointer(T t, U* u) {return addPointer(&t, *u);}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f32bba35110b6a27).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the whole SFINAE here, you can achieve this much more easily by simple template specialization:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct  addPointer
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct addPointer<T,U*>
{
    typedef typename addPointer<T*,U>::type type;
};


int main()
{
    using t = addPointer<int***, int*>::type;
}
```

If you absolutely want to use `enable_if` and a function instead of a traits-struct, the following approach would work:

```
#include <type_traits>
template <typename T, typename U,
          typename K = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer<U>::value>>
auto addPointer(T, U) -> T;

template <typename T, typename U,
          typename K = std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<U>::value>>
auto addPointer(T, U)
    -> decltype(addPointer(std::declval<std::add_pointer_t<T>>(),
                           std::declval<std::remove_pointer_t<U>>()));    
int main()
{
    using t =
        decltype(addPointer(std::declval<int***>(), std::declval<int*>()));
}
```